# Modify mootools lazyload to use class as container instead of id

Tags: javascript, mootools, lazy-loading

Below is the standard mootools lazyload code. I need to modify the code to accept a div Class as the lazyload container rather than the div ID. Any ideas how? Using IDs in combination with Ajax stops the lazyload from working as it should because the page doesnt reload so it thinks the newly loaded content with the same ID is a second instance of that ID rather than the same element. Thanks.

```
    var LazyLoad = new Class({

        Implements: [Options,Events],

        /* additional options */
        options: {
            range: 100,
            elements: ".lazy",
            container: "post-list",
            mode: "vertical",
            realSrcAttribute: "data-src",
            useFade: true
        },

        /* initialize */
        initialize: function(options) {

            // Set the class options
            this.setOptions(options);

            // Elementize items passed in
            this.container = document.getElementById(this.options.container);
            this.elements = $$(this.options.elements);

            // Set a variable for the "highest" value this has been
            this.largestPosition = 0;

            // Figure out which axis to check out
            var axis = (this.options.mode == "vertical" ? "y": "x");

            // Calculate the offset
            var offset = (this.container != window && this.container != document.body ? this.container : "");

            // Find elements remember and hold on to
            this.elements = this.elements.filter(function(el) {
                // Make opacity 0 if fadeIn should be done
                if(this.options.useFade) el.setStyle("opacity",0);
                // Get the image position
                var elPos = el.getPosition(offset)[axis];
                // If the element position is within range, load it
                if(elPos < this.container.getSize()[axis] + this.options.range) {
                    this.loadImage(el);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            },this);

            // Create the action function that will run on each scroll until all images are loaded
            var action = function(e) {

                // Get the current position
                var cpos = this.container.getScroll()[axis];

                // If the current position is higher than the last highest
                if(cpos > this.largestPosition) {

                    // Filter elements again
                    this.elements = this.elements.filter(function(el) {

                        // If the element is within range...
                        if((cpos + this.options.range + this.container.getSize()[axis]) >= el.getPosition(offset)[axis]) {

                            // Load the image!
                            this.loadImage(el);
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;

                    },this);

                    // Update the "highest" position
                    this.largestPosition = cpos;
                }

                // relay the class" scroll event
                this.fireEvent("scroll");

                // If there are no elements left, remove the action event and fire complete
                if(!this.elements.length) {
                    this.container.removeEvent("scroll",action);
                    this.fireEvent("complete");
                }

            }.bind(this);

            // Add scroll listener
            this.container.addEvent("scroll",action);
        },
        loadImage: function(image) {
            // Set load event for fadeIn
            if(this.options.useFade) {
                image.addEvent("load",function(){
                    image.fade(1);
                });
            }
            // Set the SRC
            image.set("src",image.get(this.options.realSrcAttribute));
            // Fire the image load event
            this.fireEvent("load",[image]);
        }
    });

    /* do it! */
        window.addEvent("domready",function() {
            var lazyloader = new LazyLoad({/*
                onScroll: function() { console.warn("scroll!"); },
                onLoad: function(img) { console.warn("load!", img); },
                onComplete: function() { console.warn("complete!"); }
                */
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `initialize` function, replace:

```
// Elementize items passed in
this.container = document.getElementById(this.options.container);
this.elements = $$(this.options.elements);
```

With:

```
// Elementize items passed in
this.container = $$(this.options.container)[0];
this.elements = $$(this.options.elements);
```

And then you can give any selector string (as `'.yourClass'`, but also `'.some[complex=selector]'`) as `container` class option. The first element matching that selector will be used as container. Let me know if it works.